# quarkus optaplanner illegal reflective call

Tags: java, quarkus, optaplanner

I have upgraded my JDK to version 17.
Now when I try to run parametized unit tests with optaplanner running on Quarkus I get the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private transient java.util.NavigableMap java.util.TreeSet.m accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @724b93a8

[ERROR] org.m.s.c.score.constraints.SecConflictTest.secConflictTest(String, int, Agent)[2]  Time elapsed: 0.011 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.TreeSetConverter$Reflections

[ERROR] org.m.s.c.score.constraints.SecConflictTest.secConflictTest(String, int, Agent)[3]  Time elapsed: 0.014 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.TreeSetConverter$Reflections
```

After reading a bit about this kind of problem I have added

```
--add-opens java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/java.awt.font=ALL-UNNAMED
```

to my Maven POM in the following sections: Quarkus-maven-plugin config and maven-surefire-config

```
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>--enable-preview --add-opens java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/java.awt.font=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                    <jvmArgs>--enable-preview --add-opens java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/java.awt.font=ALL-UNNAMED</jvmArgs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <parameters>${maven.compiler.parameters}</parameters>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>
                        --add-opens java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/java.awt.font=ALL-UNNAMED
                    </argLine>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

and in maven-failsafe-plugin config for profile native:

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>native</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <argLine>
                                        --add-opens java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED
                                        --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
                                        --add-opens java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED
                                        --add-opens java.desktop/java.awt.font=ALL-UNNAMED
                                    </argLine>
                                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                                        <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <properties>
                <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

**It does work as intended: tests are running fine, but I have "lost" live reload feature of quarkus**
If I change anything in my code and call a WS again, here is the error:

```
Error restarting Quarkus
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error: invalid flag: --enable-preview --add-opens
            java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens
            java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/java.awt.font=ALL-UNNAMED
```

I'm looking for a configuration allowing Quarkus with Optaplanner to run on Java 17, with ParametizedTests running fine and live reloading still working.
For information, with simple tests (no Parametized), it does work without specific `--add-open` config.

Here is the post that leads me on the path for my first fix:
https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/10303#issuecomment-666492921

Comment: This problem, I'm afraid, has nothing to do with either OptaPlanner or Quarkus. It is XStream who is making those illegal reflective calls - and the way to avoid those is to not use XStream. You are welcome to use other persistence mechanisms supported by OptaPlanner, such as JAXB, JSON etc.

Comment: @LukášPetrovický thanks for your comment, I will try it and let you know :)

Comment: Which version of OptaPlanner and Quarkus are you using?

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet for quarkus it's 2.3.0.Final
for optaplanner it's 8.11.1.Final

Answer (score 1):

I actually add the --add-opens... line to the javac parameters
That was breaking the livereload.

By using this add-opens parameters only on JVMArgs on quarkus-maven-plugin, it works as intended. and Live Reload is working also.

Btw I'm still looking for a solution to not have to add any add-opens parameters

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 possible causes for this issue (I can't see which one it is):

1. You're using OptaPlanner 7.
   Fix: Upgrade to OptaPlanner 8, which uses JAXB instead of XStream. The Quarkus extension for OptaPlanner 8 is stable and reliable (the one in 7 is not).
2. You're loading a dataset with XStream, before calling OptaPlanner, possibly through using optaplanner-persistence-xstream. That's an XStream issue with JDK 17. (See Lukas's comment.) Maybe upgrading to a new version of XStream fixes it, I hope.